# Deserialized JSON object not null for wrong type

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

If i have the following c# record:

```
public record MyRecord(string EndPoint, string Id);
```

and i have some json that i attempt to deserialize to my type:

```
var myType= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyRecord>(
            jsonStr,
            new JsonSerializerOptions
            {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
            }
        );

      if(myType is null)
      {
         ...
      }
```

where `jsonStr` is not of type `MyRecord` but some other type, the resulting `myType` rather then being null, is simply an instance of MyRecord but with empty properties. How can i check that the returned type is invalid if its not null ?

Comment: Just an idea: Does it help to deserialize as a nullable type? `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyRecord?>(...)`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes no i'm afraid

Comment: Try Newtonsoft.Json, if you can. It has a setting for instructing the deserializer to throw an exception when it encounters a json property that is not present in the .NET target type for the respective json object. Dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KW1LLV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonSerializer` does not make assumptions about the lack of contents of a json string, provided that it is at least in the same format as the target structure (e.g. `"{ }"`).

As a result, you need to check one of your properties for validity as well as the object itself:

```
var jsonStr = "{}";

var myType = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyRecord>(
        jsonStr,
        new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        }
    );

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myType?.Id))
{
    var x = myType;
}
```

Note that the behavior is identical for classes as well:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string EndPoint { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

var myType2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(
        jsonStr,
        new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        }
    );

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myType2?.Id))
{
    var x = myType;
}
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, you *can* choose to create a custom converter that overrides the serialization behavior.

```
public class MyRecordConverter : JsonConverter<MyRecord>
{
    public override MyRecord Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        var endpoint = string.Empty;
        var id = string.Empty;
        
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                break;
            }
            
            var propertyName = reader.GetString();
            reader.Read();
            
            if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(MyRecord.EndPoint),
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                endpoint = reader.GetString();
            }
            else if (propertyName.Equals(nameof(MyRecord.Id), 
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                id = reader.GetString();
            }
        }
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpoint) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
        {
            return null;
        }
        
        return new MyRecord(endpoint, id);
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyRecord value, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When passed to your Deserialize call:

```
var myType3 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyRecord>(
        jsonStr,
        new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
            Converters =
            {
                new MyRecordConverter()
            }
        }
    );
```

the above empty json object will return null instead of an initialized record.

Comment: ok fair enough - i was hoping there was a way on testing the object but if that's not possible then i'll settle on testing the property

Comment: @auburg, there is technically a way with System.Text.Json. Although i doubt that it would be practical due to the work involved. Because you would need to write a custom JsonConverter for your record type which has to process the json data of the given json object and then figure out whether all json properties can be mapped to the record type or not. If yes, then the converter would produce and return a record instance with the data. If no, it would simply return null.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace that's a great point.

Comment: @auburg, for completeness' sake, I also added  JsonConverter option to my answer.